# Create shortcut to folder for use in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, alias

I’d like to make a shortcut to a folder and be able to manipulate it.

For example I have the folder:

```
/media/Music
```

And the folder:

```
/media/Downloads
```

I’d like to move the contents from downloads to folder. I now have to do this:

```
cd /media/Downloads
ls
mv ./* /media/Music
```

I’d like to do this:

```
ls d
mv d/* m
```

Of course this is an example of a simple short folder, in practice the paths are longer.

I’ve tried to add an alias or create a function:

```
alias d='/media/Downloads'
function d () { /media/Downloads }
```

But this did not work unfortunately

I’ve also tried a program that is called [`gogo`](https://github.com/mgoral/gogo) but it also did not help.

thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You could of course `( cd /media && mv Downloads/* Music )`

Comment: Single character names for anything are risky. One extra space in a command or any other typo and you can wipe out data. Imagine if you wanted to do `rm -rf crud` and you mistyped it as `rm -rf cru d`. There goes your /media/Downloads directory! You should try to use 3 or more characters in any name just to reduce the risk of shooting yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a symlink:

```bsh
ln -s /media/Downloads d
ln -s /media/Music m
mv d/* m
```

Answer (score 1):

Both the alias and function end up trying to *run* the path /media/Downloads, which is not a program. You might want a *variable* if you're going to refer to a path a lot, such as `downloads=/media/Downloads`.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a repetitive action you can create a shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /media
mv Downloads/* Music
```

Give it a suggestive name (mv-files.sh). Make it executable

```
chmod +x mv-files.sh
```

And invoke it every time that you want to move the files

```
./mv-files.sh
```